# Xcode 6: Search for whole word in Show Document Items

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 6 when I open the method list (officially called "Show Document Items", also invoked via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>) and start typing, it shows me all the methods containing the typed letters, but not as the whole word.

As an example, let's say, I have a `Video` class with methods `standby()` and `setMaxBitrate(unsigned int bitrate)`. When I type `standb` I still have `setMaxBitrate` shown because Xcode thinks it "matches" the pattern I typed:
[image: method filter]

Is there a way to tell Xcode I only want to see items that contain what I typed as a consecutive characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change how the method list in the Jump Bar works, but you can easily navigate in a different way that searches in terms of consecutive characters. For example, use the Symbol Navigator instead, along with the filter bar at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: The problem with Symbol Navigator is that it's much slower and it will show me all symbols that have `standby` in the name for the whole project, while I'm interested only in the specific file.

Comment: Well, as the first sentence in my answer says, you can't change how the method list in the Jump Bar works. That's just how it is.

Comment: Also, the symbol navigator divides things up by _class_, which is the same as saying "the specific file". So you can easily focus on the right thing.